# How can I authenticate a user from an email link?

Tags: autologin

Our web app. sends reports out to users which contain links that point to various items within our web app. (specific records). Users ordinarily have to login to our system to access it, so I am wondering what the best methods are of allowing one of these links to direct the user to the area of the system, without them having to repeatedly login.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you create a link, you can note which user this link is for. When user clicks on the link, fetch information for the user. Guid in your url would guarantee that no other person can guess path for that users data. This will not technically authenticate a user. But will allow them to see data you need.

Comment: I would prefer the links NOT to be user-centric, in case the email got forwarded on to someone that didn't have the necessary privileges to view the same information.

Comment: Then what it the point of the link, if forwarded, it can authenticate any one to user whom the link was shared with originally? Only other option is for your system to know that the user is not authenticated, prompt for login and redirect user to the appropriate page.

Comment: I could have a GUID in the link which redirects the user to the correct area of the system, but it is how to authenticate them beforehand. I was thinking that if the browser was already open, after they had logged in, then clicking the URL from the link could check a session cookie (?) to see if the logged in user has the correct access rights - not sure of what the correct process of doing this is?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's bad idea to distribute user credentials even to a known email address. 
You can generate a unique key for each customer and insert it in query string of included URL in the email. once user clicks on the sent URL, system discovers which user is dealing with and authenticates user. After successful authentication process it really makes sense if you disable the sent unique key.